# Missing a Geom field in PostGis

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, geometry

I am working in  a Database preaparation for that I exported a shapefile from Qgis to PostGis.The Problem is this: In Qgis I can see a Polygon feature but when the same polygon feature is exported to postgis the particular fields is missing its Geom what is the problem behind it?

Comment: The polygon that you see in QGIS is it from Shapefile or Postgis source?

Comment: postgis gis source which has been exported as shapefile

Comment: What type of geometry is the feature? (Polygon, MultiPolygon, MultiGeometry, etc) Also, are all of the features in that PostGIS layer that same type?

Comment: its a polygon feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS, the geometry field is not displayed when you open the attribute table.
If the feature is displayed then it exists for sure. In your case, it must have been imported with another name.
You can depict its name either by looking directly in the database with pgadmin or other postgresql tools but you can also click the layer properties and in the metadata section you can find in the "Source for this layer" field the name of the geometry field 
(e.g. dbname='gisdb' host=geoserver port=5432 sslmode=disable key='tid' srid=3844 type=POLYGON table="raport"."test_polygons" (**geom**) sql=". 
In this case the name is geom.
You can also use QGIS's DBManager and when you click on the layer the geometry column name will be under POSTGIS, in the "Column:" row.

If this isn't satisfying then please rephrase the question.

You can check for geometry validity by clicking in QGIS --> Vector --> Geometry tools --> Check geometry validity and you can also make use of ST_IsValid in Postgis/DBManager
 (e.g.     `select id_column from your_table where ST_IsValid(the_geom_column) = 'f';`    ) to check for invalid geometries.